# What does "sudo add-apt-repository" do?

Tags: apt, ppa

A guide (on how to install a Notepad++ alternative for Linux)
told me to type this command to the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
```

What does this command do?

Answer (score 7):

`sudo` runs the following command as an administrator.

`add-apt-repository` adds the following repository to the list of places the system goes to look for software.

`ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq` is the name of the repository where the notepadqq team upload updates to their software.

One you run this command, you will be able to **install** notepadqq by typing

```
sudo apt-get install notepadqq
```

and if you install it this way, the system update program will also find and install updates to notepadqq.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference check the man pages or [www.explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com)
[image]